# Change the class of target DIV with jQuery featured slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here http://jsfiddle.net/comparebest/yBcKk/6/ I have a jQuery slider and two Divs - DIV ONE and DIV TWO.

Is there a way I can have it automatically:

1) Replace the class of DIV ONE (from "test" to "testc") when slider shows Slide 1.

2) Replace DIV TWO's class (from "test1" to "test1c") when slider shows Slide 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i came up with a solution that uses the index of your `.paging a.active` check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBcKk/9/)
here is what i added inside your rotate function:

```
 if ($('.paging a.active').index() == 0){
                //alert('slide1');  
            $('.test').removeClass('test').addClass('testc').html('DIV ONE now has class: testc');          
            }
        if ($('.paging a.active').index() == 1){
                //alert('slide1');  
            $('.test1').removeClass('test1').addClass('test1c').html('DIV TWO now has class: test1c');          
            }
```

basically, if .paging a.active index = 0 (really slide one) then change div accordingly. it just doesnt work well with the initial loading of the slider because the rotate function doesnt get called until it moves to slide two..

Comment: Ok it's almost what I've been looking for. How can I make it switch back to its original class after slider loads another slide? Initial loading is not a problem - I am planing to use first slide as an intro anyway.

Comment: just need to add an else statement to reset the classes... check out the updated [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yBcKk/10/)..

this is what i added: `else{
            $('.testc').removeClass('testc').addClass('test').html('DIV ONE now has class: test');    
        }`